# Kotlin extension bugs

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a problem. I got an old project, what wrote in kotlin.It is 1.0.2 version but i got a compiler extension.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.util.containers.EmptyIterator
```

And it is the build.gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "eu.***.**.**"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.13"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'   }
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull'
}
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.+'
compile 'com.github.buchandersenn:android-permission-manager:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.5.6'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.2'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
}
```

If I add 1.0.4 version of kotlin i got this :
Unresolved reference: brickred
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter

I have to modify this app, but i can't compile it.I spend 2 days for compile , so I need help. Thank you for help.

Comment: The indentation got messed up. Please make the code readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think plugin 'kotlin-android-extensions' has been discontinued or something.

Please align your build.gradle with https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html